# Why am I getting this error in C for the following lines of code?

Tags: c, math, logic

For these two lines of code, I get the following errors.

```
a=(sin(x)+ fc cos(x));
```

I get Error expected ')'.

For this line of code,

```
b=cos(x)-fc sin(x);
```

I get error expected ';' after expression.

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong ?.

Comment: How is `fc` defined?

Comment: Show more code.  How are these variables declared? What are their types? Is this scoped to a function? How is that function declared?

Comment: It looks like your intention is to multiply `±fc` with the result of `cos/sin(x)` ? If so, unlike in algebra, you can't just put terms adjacent to eachother to multiply them in C, you need to use the multiplication operator `*` explicitly... **Please clarify your intent for this code. What are you trying to achieve?**

Answer (score 1):

In C, multiplication of two variables requires an explicit "times" operator.

Instead of:

```
a=(sin(x)+ fc cos(x));  // Implied multiplication of fc and cos(x)
```

I think you mean:

```
a = (sin(x) + fc * cos(x)); // EXPLICIT multiplication.
```

Comment: fc represents the friction coefficient. It's supposed to be one variable.

Comment: @AJPbvj on another tack you can see the result of using poorly named variables. Had you used say `fricoeff` instead of `fc` the intention would have been more obvious. But `fc` needs additional explanation.